# Android, drawable editor doesn't show anything, How to activate it?

Tags: android, layout, drawable, graphic, activation

I have problem with activation of graphical layout. I want to see what I have done in XML, but graphical layout doesn't show any thing.

Also in res/layout, I right clicked on each XML files then went to "Open with/Legacy android drawable editor". Still nothing!

How can I activate it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have met the same problem sometimes,but close and reopen the file and it was ok,I just don't know why...

Comment: Thanks dear topxebec, You are right. I restarted my eclipse and its ok now. :)

Answer (score 0):

What views are you trying to display in the graphical layout?  The graphical layout is meant, in general, for basic android widgets/views (Button, Radio, TextView, etc.), and *will not* display custom views.

Comment: Thanks dear lrAndroid, When you start to write xml for UI, you have two choices, "Graphical Layout" and your XML file. When you write code by switching to other tab (below the screen) you can see what you have done. this feature sometimes is active and sometimes is inactive for me. At the moment it is inactive and I need to see the result instead of run the application in emulator or my device.

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: Also a screenshot would help.

Comment: Thanks, I have added screen shot. there is no error. just i can't see the graphical layout.

Comment: The only thing that looks different from mine is that you don't appear to have a Locale selected.  On my graphical layout, the Locale is set to "Any locale."

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions I have seen so far worked for me.

But, finally discovered this one.
Goto "Palette" dropdown menu and select "Show previews"

after this, I never has this issue again.
I am using ADT 20.0.3